# Set report (RDLC) as always landscape printing and A4

Tags: c#, reporting-services, printing, rdlc

Is there a way to set an RDLC report to be always Landscape and to always use A4 without the need of manually doing so every time through the print dialog?  I've been at this for a few hours and nothing came up after googling.

Indeed, is there a way to skip the print dialog in itself?

TIA

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can certainly avoid the print dialog and print directly, also you can specify page size and print orientation in code. We do it in our projects but the code is a bit of muddle plus it's in VB so I won't post a chunk of it here.

MSDN has a page titled [Walkthrough: Printing a Local Report without Preview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252091%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). This code has some XML to set the page size:

```
      "  <PageWidth>8.5in</PageWidth>" + _
      "  <PageHeight>11in</PageHeight>" + _
```

Change this to `29.7cm` & `21cm` for A4 Landscape.

Comment: Thanks and terribly sorry for the extremely late reply, but I've been without internet for 9 days!

Comment: @hawbsl Setting up deviceInfo parameter through string XML did the trick.

Comment: Could you please help me with this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55633350/how-to-show-report-data-in-center-of-rdlc-report

Answer (score 4):

As A4 size is  8.3 inches × 11.7 inches(Portrait).

So you need to set it to

report properties>Layout>Set page width and height.

Or you can manually print the report.

Look at this tutorial

[Printing  RDLC Report manually](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252091.aspx)

Comment: Programmatically? On the fly?  I have a few hundred reports with a prefix in the name that specifies the direction.

Comment: Zain Ali Setting up deviceInfo parameter through string XML did the trick.

Answer (score 3):

Double click on your report (ex: report1.rdlc) in Solution Explorer then right click on the report page and select Report Properties and you can select your prefer paper size and orientation as shown below

[image]