# How to specify page orientation for specific pages in an rdlc report

Tags: c#, rdlc

I have an rdlc report that will be a variable number of pages long, depending on the data that's used.  What I need is for the first page and last page of this report to be in Portrait orientation, while all other pages are in Landscape orientation.  I've searched quite a bit now, but haven't found a solution to this.  Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6175299/set-report-rdlc-as-always-landscape-printing-and-a4

Comment: This doesn't answer my question, since this person wants to always have the same orientation set.